# How to access Azure log analytics via API

Tags: azure, api, azure-log-analytics

I am using Azure log analytics to collect metrics for our Blob Storage account.
I have saved queries which I can run from Azure UI portal.

I want to access the same query results via API.
I couldn't find any decent documentation on how this can be done.

Can someone point me into right direction?

thanks

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview.